# What's causing authentication error when pushing Docker image to Google Container Registry?

Tags: docker, google-kubernetes-engine, circleci, google-container-registry

I am trying to push a Docker image to Google Container Registry from a CircleCI build, as per [their instructions](https://circleci.com/docs/continuous-deployment-with-google-container-engine/). However, pushing to GCR fails due to an apparent authentication error:

```
Using 'push eu.gcr.io/realtimemusic-147914/realtimemusic-test/realtimemusic-test' for DOCKER_ARGS.
The push refers to a repository [eu.gcr.io/realtimemusic-147914/realtimemusic-test/realtimemusic-test] (len: 1)

Post https://eu.gcr.io/v2/realtimemusic-147914/realtimemusic-test/realtimemusic-test/blobs/uploads/: token auth attempt for registry: https://eu.gcr.io/v2/token?account=oauth2accesstoken&scope=repository%3Arealtimemusic-147914%2Frealtimemusic-test%2Frealtimemusic-test%3Apush%2Cpull&service=eu.gcr.io request failed with status: 403 Forbidden
```

I've prior to pushing the Docker image authenticated the service account against Google Cloud:

```
echo $GCLOUD_KEY | base64 --decode > ${HOME}/client-secret.json
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file ${HOME}/client-secret.json
gcloud config set project $GCLOUD_PROJECT_ID
```

Then I build the image and push it to GCR:

```
docker build -t $EXTERNAL_REGISTRY_ENDPOINT/realtimemusic-test -f docker/test/Dockerfile .
gcloud docker push -- $EXTERNAL_REGISTRY_ENDPOINT/realtimemusic-test
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Another issue I'm seeing in our logs is that 'realtime-music-147914' project doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: @jsand Ugh yes, there is a rogue dash in the project name I see now :( Not sure if I made that mistake consistently though, doing another build now with that issue rectified.

Comment: @jsand I fixed the project name, and the error turned into 403, which I guess makes sense since it indicates a permission error rather than a bad request. I'm pretty sure I saw 403 yesterday, so the extra dash in the project name was probably intermittent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The service account requires permission to write to the Cloud Storage bucket containing the container registry. Granting the service account either the project editor role or write access to the bucket (via ACL) solves the issue. The latter should be preferable since the account doesn't receive wider permissions than it needs.

Answer (score 2):

After many retries... I solved using access token:

```
gcloud auth print-access-token | docker login -u oauth2accesstoken --password-stdin https://[HOSTNAME]
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the _json_key method for authenticating with Docker?
https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

After that, please use naked 'docker' (without 'gcloud').

Comment: Do you think I might need to give the service account permission to push to the registry? I just haven't figured out how to tell yet if it has the right permissions or not.

Comment: The service account needs Editor permissions in order to create a GCS bucket, which is what your container registry is backed by.
What you're doing should be fine, actually. If you have a service account as the active gcloud account, 'gcloud docker' should inject a valid access token, as long as the service account has editor permissions.

Comment: I think that might be exactly the thing, I hadn't given the service account editor permissions. I guess I thought initially that it would be giving it too much control, so I only assigned it the Service Account Actor role. Also, the CircleCI guide doesn't say anything about which role to assign to the service account, so I was unsure.

Comment: Anyway, I'm trying again now, having granted the service account the Editor role, so we will see.

Comment: Yep, that was the issue! I don't feel right about granting Editor role to the service account though, I wish there were a straight forward way to just allow it to push images.

Comment: Would getting the service account set up [using ACLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/?hl=en#applyacls) rather than giving it project-level permissions solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks, looks like making the service account the owner of just the image bucket does the trick and is certainly less invasive than project wide access.

Comment: We aim to please, happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pushing docker image using google cloud sdk. You can use temporary authorization with the following command:

```
  gcloud docker --authorize-only
```

The above command gives you a temporary authorization for pushing and pulling images using docker.
You can refer this link for details [Gcloud docker](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/docker).
Hope it helps to solve your issue.